# PyQt5 styleSheet Animation

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qpropertyanimation

I am using PyQt5 to build an app with multiple buttons.
What I am trying to accomplish is to create a blinking background color (yellow-red) for some of my buttons.

```
btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: green; color: red; font-weight: 800; font-size: 22")
tobyte = 'styleSheet'
a = bytearray(tobyte, 'utf-8')
animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(' + 'btn' + str(yy) + ', a)
animation.setDuration(1000)
animation.setLoopCount(1000)
animation.setStartValue("background-color: yellow; color: red; font-weight: 800; font-size: 22")
animation.setEndValue("background-color: red; color: red; font-weight: 800; font-size: 22")
animation.start()
```

The animation starts (it removes the predefined, green background), but it doesn't change the background color of the button to yellow or red.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You ought not to animate stylesheets because there are the vagueness which specifically value must be animated (interpolated). There are not internal parser of stylesheet into PyQt5 classes.
Nevertheless there are ways to solve the problem.
Below is working example for animated QLabel (background-color of QLabel).

Main idea consists in using the custom **QtCore.QPropertyAnimation**. In this case its name is **zcolor**. Also you ought to create property **QtCore.pyqtProperty** in class derived from **QLabel** (and any other class).

Moreover you can use several animation in your class, in example you can switch between three types of animation (No animation, type 1, type 2).

Of course **some** params of **some** widgets can be animated via **QtGui.QPalette.Window** without parse of ss (see three strings in comment starting with *# pal = self.palette()*), however the way via stylesheets is more flexible IMHO.

```
import sys
import re

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFormLayout, QLabel, QDialog, QLineEdit, QPushButton)

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui


class AnimatedLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        QLabel.__init__(self)

        color1 = QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)
        color2 = QtGui.QColor(255, 144, 0)
        color3 = QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 0)
        color4 = QtGui.QColor(224, 192, 192)

        color5 = QtGui.QColor(192, 224, 192)
        color6 = QtGui.QColor(192, 192, 192)
        color7 = QtGui.QColor(212, 208, 200)

        self.co_get = 0
        self.co_set = 0

        byar = QtCore.QByteArray()
        byar.append('zcolor')
        self.color_anim = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, byar)
        self.color_anim.setStartValue(color4)
        self.color_anim.setKeyValueAt(0.15, color1)
        self.color_anim.setKeyValueAt(0.3, color2)
        self.color_anim.setKeyValueAt(0.5, color3)
        self.color_anim.setKeyValueAt(0.75, color2)
        self.color_anim.setEndValue(color4)
        self.color_anim.setDuration(2000)
        self.color_anim.setLoopCount(1)

        self.color_anim_ok = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, byar)
        self.color_anim_ok.setStartValue(color5)
        self.color_anim_ok.setKeyValueAt(0.5, color6)
        self.color_anim_ok.setEndValue(color7)
        self.color_anim_ok.setDuration(1000)
        self.color_anim_ok.setLoopCount(-1)

        self.custom_anim = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, byar)

    def parseStyleSheet(self):
        ss = self.styleSheet()
        sts = [s.strip() for s in ss.split(';') if len(s.strip())]
        return sts

    def getBackColor(self):
        self.co_get += 1
        # print(fuin(), self.co_get)
        return self.palette().color(self.pal_ele)

    def setBackColor(self, color):
        self.co_set += 1
        sss = self.parseStyleSheet()
        bg_new = 'background-color: rgba(%d,%d,%d,%d);' % (color.red(), color.green(), color.blue(), color.alpha())

        for k, sty in enumerate(sss):
            if re.search('\Abackground-color:', sty):
                sss[k] = bg_new
                break
        else:
            sss.append(bg_new)

        # pal = self.palette()
        # pal.setColor(self.pal_ele, color)
        # self.setPalette(pal)
        self.setStyleSheet('; '.join(sss))

    pal_ele = QtGui.QPalette.Window
    zcolor = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtGui.QColor, getBackColor, setBackColor)


# this class is only for test
class SomeDia2(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Sets up labels in form"""
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        self.co_press = 0

        self.setModal(True)
        self.setWindowTitle('Animation Example')

        self.edit_pad =  QLineEdit('-1')
        self.edit_rad =  QLineEdit('-1')
        self._mapHeight = QLineEdit('0')

        self.layout = QFormLayout()
        self.lab_pad = QLabel('Padding (px):')
        self.lab_rad = QLabel('Radius (px):' )
        self.layout.addRow(self.lab_pad, self.edit_pad)
        self.layout.addRow(self.lab_rad, self.edit_rad)

        self.anila = AnimatedLabel()
        self.anila.setText('Label for animation:')
        # self.anila.setStyleSheet('padding: 0 4px; border-radius: 4px;')
        self.layout.addRow(self.anila, self._mapHeight)

        self.ok = QPushButton()
        self.ok.setText('OK -- change animation')
        self.ok.clicked.connect(self._okPress)

        self.layout.addRow(self.ok)
        self.layout.setLabelAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.set_initial_data()

    def set_initial_data(self):
        pad_vali = QtGui.QIntValidator(0, 20)
        rad_vali = QtGui.QIntValidator(0, 10)

        self.edit_pad.setValidator(pad_vali)
        self.edit_rad.setValidator(rad_vali)

        pad, rad = 4, 4
        self.edit_pad.setText(str(pad))
        self.edit_rad.setText(str(rad))

        self.set_ss(pad,rad)

        # slots
        self.edit_pad.textChanged.connect(self.change_padrad)
        self.edit_rad.textChanged.connect(self.change_padrad)

    def set_ss(self, pad, rad):
        self.anila.setStyleSheet('padding: 0 %dpx; border-radius: %dpx;' % (pad, rad))
        for lab in [self.lab_rad, self.lab_pad]:
            lab.setStyleSheet('padding: 0 %dpx;' % pad)

    def change_padrad(self):
        try:
            pad = int(self.edit_pad.text())
            rad = int(self.edit_rad.text())
            # print(pad, rad)
            self.set_ss(pad, rad)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(type(ex).__name__)

    def _okPress(self, flag):
        # print('OK PRESS', flag)
        self.co_press += 1
        typ = self.co_press % 3
        if 0 == typ:
            print('Animation NO')
            self.anila.color_anim.stop()
            self.anila.color_anim_ok.stop()
        elif 1 == typ:
            print('Animation type 1')
            self.anila.color_anim_ok.stop()
            self.anila.color_anim.start()
        elif 2 == typ:
            print('Animation type 2')
            self.anila.color_anim.stop()
            self.anila.color_anim_ok.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    dia = SomeDia2()
    dia.show()

    app.exec_()
```