# How to change QLabel Geometry periodically without blocking loops

Tags: user-interface, pyqt5, qlabel

I do like to extend this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67210133) especially the `blink` function to change the geometry of the label `setGeometry`, in particular, the starting coordinates of the label.

So according to duration, the **label will change** not only the **color** but also the **position(Geometry)** periodically.

Can you please tell me if that is possible (without blocking loops) and how can I do it please? thanks in advance.

Comment: You're already using a QPropertyAnimation, why don't you add another for the geometry or pos?

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your kind advice, your suggestion should work perfectly according to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of @musicamante here is the solution:

```py
self.pos_anim   = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"geometry")

def alarm_alert(self, pos1, pos2, duration=3000):
        """
        Function: alarm_alert, to alarm the motion of the Animated QLabel.
        ---
        Parameters:
        @param: pos1, QRect, geometry of first position.
        @param: pos2, QRect, geometry of second position.
        @param:duration, int, motion duration in ms.
        ---
        @return: None
        """
        self.pos_anim.stop()
        self.pos_anim.setDuration(duration)
        self.pos_anim.setStartValue(pos2)
        self.color_anim.setKeyValueAt(0.2, pos2)
        self.color_anim.setKeyValueAt(0.6, pos1)
        self.color_anim.setKeyValueAt(0.2, pos2)
        self.pos_anim.setEndValue(pos1)
        self.pos_anim.setLoopCount(-1)
        self.pos_anim.start()
```