# Is there a proper way to hatch QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel

As stated in the title, I do want to know if there is a proper way to hatch the `QLabel` which in my case is has the Geometry of `QRect` as you can see in my [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67192260/is-there-any-way-to-pass-existing-label-to-another-class-to-make-it-blink).

I checked the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QLabel.html) but I didn't understand how I can hatch the `QLabel`.

Here is an image of how it might the `QLabel` will look after hatching (different options):

[image: img]

Note: that I don't intend to load a `QPixmap`, and I'm looking for more neat approach.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "hatch"? Do you intend some kind of effect animation? Can you provide an actual example, even if taken from some other context?

Comment: @musicamante I mean by "*hatch*" to draw thin lines on top of the `QLabel` with a kind of slope as you can see in the image in the question.

Comment: So, you want to draw a *pattern*? Besides, those pattern are somewhat different, while the last 3 might be repeated (*tiled*), the first one is not. As said, please try to make yourself more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `QLabel`'s `paintEvent` and use `QBrush` with predefined `BrushStyle` [pattern](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html#details) or define your pattern as tiny pixmap and use as a `QBrush`.

If you need pattern on top of text (as foreground) call `super().paintEvent(event)` before drawing it, if you need it below text (as background) call `super().paintEvent(event)` after.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class LabelStandardPattern(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.save()
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.Dense6Pattern))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())
        painter.restore()
        super().paintEvent(event)


class LabelUserPattern(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, text="", parent = None):
        super().__init__(text, parent)
        image = QtGui.QImage(5,5, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        image.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(image)
        painter.drawLine(0,0,2,2)
        self._brush = QtGui.QBrush(image)
        self._image = image

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.save()
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(self._brush)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, False)
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())
        painter.restore()
        super().paintEvent(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    palette = app.palette()
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Foreground, QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.blue))

    label1 = LabelStandardPattern("Standard Pattern")
    label1.setPalette(palette)
    label1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 20))
    
    label2 = LabelUserPattern("User Pattern")
    label2.setPalette(palette)
    label2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 20))
    
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(label1)
    layout.addWidget(label2)
    widget.setLayout(layout)
    widget.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Note that it's actually not necessary to override the paint event when using standard patterns: it's enough to create a new QBrush with the color and pattern, and set that brush for the Window palette role (or any backgroundRole set for the widget). The same also goes for a pixmap when using a tiled pattern.